# Laravel Scheduling custom settings

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks

I am using the Laravel 5.7 and now I am facing the following problem:
I have a cronjobs table which contains many cronjob records. Let's take one for example:

`Record one should be repeated every 50 minutes`.

I created function `getMinutelyCronjobs` fetches from DB all the cronjobs whish has to be executed minutely.

I went this way: I created a class in Commands `Minutely.php` where I get all this cronjobs in the `handle()` function. When I initialized all the data in `Minutely.php` class, I cann call this `handle()` function using `$schedule->command('cronjobs:minutely')->everyMinute();`.

The problem is, that every cronjob could have different `minute_x`(recurrence, in my example `50`) and then the `$schedule->command('cronjobs:minutely')->everyMinute();` should be `$schedule->command('cronjobs:minutely')->everyMinute(50);`.

here is my `getMinutelyCronjobs` function :

```
public static function getMinutelyCronjobs(){
        $fields = ['id', 'protocol', 'script', 'minutes_frequency', 'login_user', 'login_password', 'email'];
        return Cronjob::select($fields)->where('minutely', 1)
               ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
               ->get();
    }
```

How could I implement this ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get by with running the task every hour instead of every 50 minutes, the first answer will work.  If you need it to be specifically every 50 minutes, you can try something like this, which should run every 50 minutes instead of every 60.

EDIT:
You didn't give the details about the data you are pulling from your database relating to the jobs, but you should be able to just do something like this to schedule each job.

```
foreach ($jobs as $job) {
    $schedule->command($job->command)->everyMinute()->when(function () {
        $now = new \DateTime;
        $minutes = floatval($now->format('G'))*60 + floatval($now->format('i'));
        return $minutes % $job->minutes == 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my comment on the previous answer please, it is not quite what I need

Comment: I updated it slightly to assume you are looping through each job and that each job could have a different schedule.  Unless I'm misunderstanding, I think that's what you wanted to accomplish.

Comment: Yup, I thought to do it that way, but I get the records in the strange Collections way which contains `table:protected`, `with:protected` and other model fields along with the records I need, do I know, what could be the problem ? When I call the same function in COntroller, I get the data in the right way(associative array)

Comment: I'm not sure what to say without seeing more data.  Did you try this?
`foreach ($jobs->toArray() as $job)`
Does that make any difference?

Comment: No, `toArray()` function is not working. I am getting the records in this way https://textuploader.com/d3w24  , and I cannot retrieve data from this Collection properly. U can see my `getMinutelyRecords` function, which gives this collection in my question, Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, It worked, I made a logic mistake, thanks for your help

Comment: Great!  Sorry, I didn't see your getMinutelyCronjobs function originally, or I would have made my suggested code match your data.

Answer (score 0):

`everyMinute()` instead of use `hourlyAt()` method

> Run the task every hour at 50 mins past the hour

```
$schedule->command('cronjobs:minutely')->hourlyAt(50);
```

for more information read this [article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#defining-schedules)

Comment: The problem is, that that was explicitly said 50 here, but it is a variable x, so I should load for every cronjob its minutes_x in the schedule function